# pandas columns must have matching element counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have very large dataframe.

```
 data["product_title"]
    0       Fashion Square New Retro Jelly Color Sunglasse...
    1         Fashion Lensless Metal Frame Diamond Sunglasses
    2       Frameless Sunglasses Metal Rice Nails New Larg...
    3       Square Small Frame Marine Sunglasses New Metal...
    4       Fluorescent Green Sunglasses Square Sunglasses...
   

data["price"]
    0       [1.20,  1.20,  1.20,  1.20,  1.20,  1.20,  1.2...
    1                                                  [6.25]
    2       [3.42,  3.42,  3.42,  3.42,  3.42,  3.42,  3.4...
    3       [2.85,  2.85,  2.85,  2.85,  2.85,  2.85,  2.8...
    4       [1.42,  1.42,  1.42,  1.42,  1.42,  1.42,  1.4...
```

Where I have multiple product titles and prices inside the list. look at the example below so you can understand:

```
    product title               price
 ["title1","title2",...]      ['5','7',....]
```

I tried this code:

```
data['product_title'] = data['product_title'].str.strip('[]').str.replace("'", '').str.split(',')
data['price'] = data['price'].str.strip('[]').str.replace("'", '').str.split(',')
data = data.explode(['product_title','price'],ignore_index=True)
```

getting this error:

```
ValueError: columns must have matching element counts
```

see the screenshot because I think it will be not good to paste the full error log here.
[image]

Comment: @jch yes I think also they might be not  same number of corresponding. Can you please post your solution as answare. I am new in python

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that you have data that doesn't have the same number of corresponding `product_title` and `price` in all rows.  After doing the first two `strip/replace/splits` do a check on the lengths of the lists.  Also you also could just convert those list-like looking strings into lists directly using `literal_eval` from `ast`.    [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

**Starting with this data frame**

```
d = {'product_title': ['["Prod1","Prod2","Prod3","Prod4"]','["Prod5","Prod6","Prod7","Prod8"]'],
'price': ['[1,2,3,4]','[5,6,7]']  }

data = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(data)

                       product_title      price
0  ["Prod1","Prod2","Prod3","Prod4"]  [1,2,3,4]
1  ["Prod5","Prod6","Prod7","Prod8"]    [5,6,7]
```

**Convert list-format strings into Python lists**

```
from ast import literal_eval

data['product_title'] = data['product_title'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))
data['price'] = data['price'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))

print(data)
                  product_title         price
0  [Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, Prod4]  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1  [Prod5, Prod6, Prod7, Prod8]     [5, 6, 7]
```

**Check to see if any lists lengths don't match**

```
(data['product_title'].str.len() != data['price'].str.len()).any()

True
```

(`True` here means that rows exist with non-matching list lengths)

**Keep the good rows**

```
good_data = data.loc[data['product_title'].str.len() == data['price'].str.len()]
print(good_data)

                  product_title         price
0  [Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, Prod4]  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: you just copy and paste your comment. It's not an answare. I want to see the code